# Why are my unanswered questions marked closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have been trying to ask good questions, trying to be as concise as possible while at the same time explaining exactly what I want in sufficient detail, and providing code I've tried to implement the desired behavior. Or if I don't know what to try, I provide examples of what I'm wishing to obtain in the form of an explanation or screenshots. I have asked some questions that don't get answered, and recently when I came back after a while to check on the stats (how many views) and to see if I can improve the question, I found it was marked [on hold]. I took a look at the reason, and it stated it's on hold because the question or the desired behavior is not clear, the question needs a clear problem statement. I then looked over the question, and to me, it was perfectly clear what I was asking. The very first sentence explains exactly what I wanted to obtain, I provided a screenshot of where it had been implemented elsewhere, and provided code that did not work. I could not find anything to improve in the question.

I took a look at other questions I had asked that hadn't yet received an answer, and found the majority of them had been put [on hold] as well, for the same reason. I read my questions and tried to figure out what wasn't clear about them and attempt to improve them, but often times I couldn't come up with anything, and thought they were good questions. In most cases the only thing I could do was **bold** or *italic* an already existing statement/question that clearly summarized what I wanted to obtain or what the issue was, or I added one at the end in attempt to make it clearer, even though I dislike emphasizing unnecessarily as I feel that is equivalent to shouting or drawing attention when it shouldn't be taken out of context.

After editing the questions and voting to reopen, now I see they have all been [closed] for the same reason - off-topic, not clear. Some of them have multiple reopen votes (but not yet 5). One person commented, stating they can't edit the question, but they fully understand what I'm asking and they have the exact same question, and that comment has been up voted, yet the question remains closed. I've tried yet again to make the questions clearer after noticing they've been closed.

Now, I noticed all of these questions were put [on hold] then [closed] by *the same person*. This was a red flag, it seemed I had been targeted. Yet it appears this person has a high reputation and is a valuable contributor. (I notice in his bio he obviously has confrontation with others whose questions he has moderated.)

**My questions are (this bolded to be clear):**

1. What did I do wrong to result in my questions being marked [on hold] when I felt, and in some questions others too, that the desired behavior or issue is sufficiently explained?
2. When I added emphasis or rephrased or made more concise my questions, why were they [closed] for the same reason?
3. What can I do to prevent this from occurring in the future?

I am left feeling uncertain, it seems odd to me that one user has the power to close questions because *they* don't understand what I'm asking (it doesn't seem this moderator has experience with Objective-C, and all these questions are iOS programming questions), while other users have the same question or do understand it.

My currently closed questions that were put [on hold] and then [closed] by Andrew Barber:
[Show Blended Layers reveals red UIImage but it does not have an alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940220/show-blended-layers-reveals-red-uiimage-but-it-does-not-have-an-alpha-channel)
[Refresh Control with Search Display Controller appears overtop the Search Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270078/refresh-control-with-search-display-controller-appears-overtop-the-search-bar)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250495/uitableviewrowanimation-isnt-the-same-every-time
[How to obtain plain 'globe' Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522898/recolor-unicode-character-in-nsstring)
[Custom cell separator lines disappear upon scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251811/custom-cell-separator-lines-disappear-upon-scrolling)

Comment: Let's take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270078/refresh-control-with-search-display-controller-appears-overtop-the-search-bar) question as an example. I copy that line of code, startup XCode and drop that line in the default project, build, deploy, run: tada there is the problem. Or do I need to do more than that?

Comment: I did state everything one would need to do to reproduce the issue. It actually requires no code. Drag out a table view controller and a search display controller, enable refreshing in the sidebar. That one line of code is an attempt to fix the issue, but does not work.

Comment: Ok, we have to wait for Andrew then to come by and explain.

Comment: I gave [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270078/refresh-control-with-search-display-controller-appears-overtop-the-search-bar) an edit. For me it looks better. Does it still capture your intent?

Comment: @rene I appreciate the help, but actually not all the screenshots match up to the text that explains the behavior so I think it will confuse people. That last paragraph is still the same topic, I wouldn't separate them myself. I don't think a simple rearranging would have prevented the question from being closed. Something with the question content caused the close, unless it was wrongfully closed.

Comment: OK, you can rollback my edit. I see you have one other commenter that makes a comment that is somewhat in line with what I tried to explain.

Comment: I just tweaked your edits, they were an improvement, just had to line up correctly.

Comment: These didn't look so bad, after your edits, so I reopened the remainder. I've pinged Andrew to come on by and explain what he saw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, for why I 'targeted' those posts - there was a flag related to them all to which I was responding. You had performed numerous edits all in a short period of time - on those specific questions. That triggers an automatic moderator flag. In responding to it, your edits seemed extremely minor to me at the time. The edits caused all of your questions to be 'bumped', yet did not contain any substantive updates to help them get answered.

From looking at the ones you've linked, it didn't look like there was enough information to really answer the questions before your edits, and no new responses had come in the many hours since those edits. In the first four cases, I didn't see enough information - code-wise in particular - to really diagnose the problems. I think the comments bear that perception out, even after the edits and reopens. I'm honestly not sure about the fifth one, though. I think I made a mistake putting that one on hold; the history doesn't present anything obvious to me here.

---

Addressing your other items:

I am an elected, diamond moderator, which explains my ability to put those questions on-hold without any other votes. That actually has nothing to do with my reputation score, for the record.

For my bio suggesting "[he] obviously has confrontation with others whose questions he has moderated"; I guess you are referring to the part where I say:

> But please keep in mind: If you have an issue with moderation, you should bring it up on Meta, and not send me Tweets about it. Seriously. I will cut you. Or, block you. Or both.

As a diamond moderator, I naturally take a very large number of actions that could be seen to be 'against' someone. Because I have my Twitter contact information there, I regularly am 'pinged' or DMed on Twitter by people asking me about those things. I don't generally consider it appropriate to engage in too much of such discussions there, so my paragraph quoted above is to try to stave some of that off.

Re this quote from your question above:

> My currently closed questions that were put [on hold] and then [closed] by Andrew Barber:

I put the questions on hold; The "Closed" part is simply the next step, and is automatic, based on the time it is left on-hold. There is actually no difference there for purposes of reopening.

---

All the above said, you've made some edits that I do think clarify things, and your questions have been reopened.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what has occurred here.

Comment: @Joey You are very welcome! :)

Comment: Hey Andrew, there's one question that remains closed and I'm not sure exactly why. To me, the question is clear, and it has 2 up-votes. But I have edited it again to try to improve the question. I believe it is sufficiently clear what I am asking, as I further clarified the desired behavior and improved wording and layout. A couple questions: do you recall the reason why it was closed, and do you believe the question is now sufficiently clear? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424165/how-to-implement-uivisualeffectview-in-uitableview-with-adaptive-segues

Comment: @Joey I've reopened it.